# Is Reflection really slow?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection

This is a common belief that reflection is slow and try to avoid it as much as possible. But is that belief true, in the current situation? There has been lot of changes in the current .net versions like, use of IL Weaving (i.e. IL Emit) etc, as opposed to traditional PropertyInfo and MethodInfo ways of performing reflection.

Is that any convincing proof, that the new reflection is not that slow any more, and can be used. Is there better way to read attribute data?

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Comment: "Is Reflection really slow?" - compared to what?

Comment: +1, although you didn't run the numbers yourself.  I have always heard this, yet I [can't think where](http://xkcd.com/125/).  Still, it's never stopped me from using reflection, which I've never found slow.  As rumors go, it's counterintuitive, at least when the code is reflecting the loaded assembly (as is often the case): if there's one thing you know is loaded into memory, it's the assembly running the code!  Should be fast as anything else.

Comment: var x = new Example(); vs Activator.CreateInstance("....");

Comment: Also, what usage of reflection are you talking about?  Obviously, building an entire dynamic invocation layer (like building a scripting language or ORM using pure reflection as opposed to code generation) is going to add one stack frame per call, which would obviously slow things down at some scale.  But common uses of reflection, such as reading attributes or loading types (which config has done frequently even before the DI fad) should be no different than anything else.

Comment: They do not do the same. It is stupid to use Activator.CreateInstance when the class is known by type, it is not avoidable when you get the name dynamically from a config of some sort. The example, thus stinks.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you think about it, reflection is pretty darn impressive in how fast it is.

A cached delegate from a `ConstructorInfo` or `MethodInfo` can be called with speed comparable to any other delegate.

A delegate created from `ILGenerator.Emit` (which incidentally isn't new, it's been in .NET since version 1) can likewise be called just as fast.

An object obtained through emitting or calling a `ConstructorInfo`'s delegate will be just as fast as any other object.

If you obtain an object by loading an assembly dynamically, using reflection to find the method to call, and calling it, and it implements a defined interface through which you call it from that point on, then it'll be just as fast in how it's used as another implementation of that interface.

In all, reflection gives us ways of doing things that without it we would - if we could do them at all - have to use techniques that are slower both to code and to execute.

It also gives us means of doing things that are more complicated, more brittle, less type-safe and less performant than other means too. Pretty much every line of C# code can be replaced by a big chunk of code that uses reflection. This code will almost certainly be worse than the original line in a whole bunch of ways, and performance is the least of them.

Quite possibly the "avoid reflection because its slow" advice stems from the belief that the sort of developer that would go nuts for any new technique just because it seemed cool would be the sort that would be more likely warned off by "it'll be slower" than by "it'll be less idiomatic, more error-prone and harder to maintain". Quite possibly this belief is completely correct.

For the most part though, when the most natural and obvious approach is to use reflection, then it also won't be less performant than a really convoluted attempt to avoid it.

If performance concerns apply to anything in reflection, its really to the uses that are hidden:

Using `dynamic` can seem sensible in a case where only a little work could avoid it. Here the performance difference may be worth considering.

In ASP.NET, using `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SomeProperty")%>` is easier but generally less performant than `<#((SomeType)Container.DataItem).SomeProperty%>` or `<%#SomeCodeBehindProvidedCallWithTheSameResult%>`. I'll still use the former 90% of the time, and the latter only if I really care about a given page's performance or more likely because doing many operations on the same object makes the latter actually more natural.

So in all, everything remains "slow" in computers while they are bounded by the requirement to work in a single universe in a way that consumes energy and takes time, for some value of "slow". Different reflection techniques have different costs, but so does the alternatives. Beware not so much of reflection in cases where it's the obvious approach as hidden reflection where another approach just slightly less obvious may serve well.

And of course, code wisely with whatever technique you use. If you're going to call the same delegate a hundred times in a row, you should be storing it rather than obtaining it each call, and that would go whether the way to obtain it was through reflection or not.

Answer (score 8):

It all depends.
Yes, using reflection is without any doubt slower than not using reflection, but you have to look at the big picture:

For example, imagine that your code does some reflection and then loads some data from a database over the network.
In this case, you can completely neglect the additional cost for reflection because the database request over the network will likely take much, much longer.

Comment: +1 and to add to this: `new T()` in generics actually is compiled to `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` and thus arguably also "reflection usage". Would one write different code because of just that? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about the performance cost that much.  Not saying performance doesn't matter, but in a lot of cases, a millisecond or two isn't noticeable or worth choosing a more complicated coding alternative. Take a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/02/19/reflection-speed-test-how-slow-is-it-really.aspx).

I generally prefer this approach:

1. write simple code
2. measure performance
3. optimize the biggest hitter, if needed

Answer (score 1):

Whad do you mean by mentioning **a common belief**? Reflection is not a solid block. You should consider each method apart. For instance, creating an object through a default constructor is few times slower than a simple call, whilst creating a parametered constructor is tens time slower. So if you want to study the speed, do a benchmark and benchmark the concrete functions you need.

PS. Using C#, you can always create and [compile expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) on the fly which if you manage to do it would be much faster than reflection.

Answer (score 0):

yes reflection is slow when we try to do on bulky opertations or with in a loop.
you can try out dynamic options as well . with dynamic option its can be cached and eventually will be faster than reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to look at attributes applied to source code, then you pretty much have to use reflection.

Some reflection operations are fast, such as Object.GetType(), but some operations are relatively slow, such as Type.FindMethod("MyMethod").

In general, I would say that if your application makes occasional use of Reflection, there should be no performance concern.  On the other hand, if your application uses Reflection extensively, then you might observe some slowness.

Answer (score 0):

Introspection is an heavy job. Saying slow is relative to a lot of things. Invoking method/constructor through reflection is slow, but using reflection to only retreive metadatas is not.

Keep in mind, reflection must be only use to retrieve metadatas. 
If you need to invoke method, running something, just emit dynamic types/methods at initialization time and invoke them through interfaces/delegates.